# Anchor href doesn't work when i add dynamically hr tag after user click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, django

```
        <div class="nav-center">
            <ul class="center">
                <a class="nav-item" href="">
                    <li>Random facts</li>
                    <hr class="line"> 
                </a>
                <a class="nav-item" href="/blog/technology/">
                    <li>Technology</li>
                </a>
                <a class="nav-item" href="/blog/sport/">
                    <li>Sports</li>
                </a>
                <a class="nav-item" href="">
                    <li>About poeters</li>
                </a>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

//JavaScript Code

```
let navItems = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-item");
let addchild = document.createElement("hr");
addchild.classList.add("line");
let Handler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    navItems.forEach((node) => {
        if (node.contains(removechild)){
            node.removeChild(removechild);
    }
  });
  e.currentTarget.appendChild(addchild);
};
navItems.forEach((node) => {
  node.addEventListener("click", Handler);
});
```

See the first anchor tag i added hr tag through html it is showing line below **Random Facts** and also works fine for my expected link.. But when i add dynamically after user click, line shows but anchor link does not work after user click why??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: Your HTML is invalid

Here is a version that tests the URL. This script needs to be in all pages

***[LIVE DEMO](https://plungjan.name/blog/)***

```js
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  // const url = new URL(location.href); // uncomment on your server
  const url = new URL("https://www.yourserver.com/blog/technology/");
  const path = url.pathname;
  let where = path.split("/")
  if (!where[where.length-1]) where.pop() // last part of url ending with /
  where = where.pop(); // now we have the folder or filename
  console.log("w",where,"path",path)
  const link = document.querySelector(".nav-center a[href*='"+where+"']"); 
  if (link) link.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createElement("hr"), link.nextSibling);
  else console.log("from path",path,"where not found",where)
})
```

```html
<script src="/blog/scripts/nav.js"></script>
<div class="nav-center">
  <ul class="center">
    <li><a class="nav-item" href="/blog/index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-item" href="/blog/random/">Random facts</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-item" href="/blog/technology/">Technology</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-item" href="/blog/sport/">Sports</a><br/></li>
    <li><a class="nav-item" href="/blog/about/">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<h1>Home</h1>
```

Here is a version that expect you to fetch/ajax your pages into the existing page. Also it is using delegation

```js
let nav = document.querySelector(".nav-center ul");
let addchild = document.createElement("hr");
addchild.classList.add("line");

const handler = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const tgt = e.target.closest("li");
  const url = tgt.querySelector("a")?.href ?? "";
  if (url) {  
    nav.querySelector(".line")?.remove();
    tgt.querySelector("a").appendChild(addchild);
    // here you would ajax the href into a div elsewhere or target an iFrame
    console.log(url)
  }
};
nav.addEventListener("click", handler);
```

```html
<div class="nav-center">
  <ul class="center">
    <li><a class="nav-item" href="">Random facts</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-item" href="/blog/technology/">Technology</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-item" href="/blog/sport/">Sports</a><br/></li>
    <li><a class="nav-item" href="">About poeters</a></li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: After click on Technology Just line is showing below it and do not change the link..

Comment: It is not clear what you actually want. So I guessed - you cannot change the page AND keep the underline, so you need to fetch the page into another element on the page or in an iframe

Comment: If you want to change the page AND the underline, then your script needs to interrogate the URL and undeline the relevant navline and the nav script has to be on every page

Comment: i want when user click on Technology it go to technology page and show below the line of it.. when click on Random Facts go to that page and show the line below Random Facts...

Comment: it is the base.html file and navbar in django which is shows every page in my website..

Comment: it does not working why are you not using querySelectorAll??

Comment: You can tell me the other method to perform that...

Comment: Send me your WhatsApp i will give you zip file then you will check it by yourself..

Comment: Just put a test file on your server and post a link

Comment: Please see update. I fixed the script to match the HTML I posted too